# Getting an error while creating a Foreign Key

Tags: mysql

I was following W3Schools' guide on how to create a `Foreign Key` but every time I try to run my code it gives me an error. 
**My code**

```
CREATE TABLE students(
    `Student Number` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `First Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `Last Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    City VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    State VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Zip INT NOT NULL,
    `Date of Birth` DATE NOT NULL,
    `Major ID` INT,
    Advisor VARCHAR(255),
    `Enroll Date` DATE,
    `Total Credits Complete` INT,
    FOREIGN KEY `Major ID` REFERENCES Major(`Major ID`)
);
```

I'm trying to give `'Major ID'` a `Foreign Key` but instead I get this error code

> Error
>  SQL query:
>
> CREATE TABLE students(
>       `Student Number` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
>       `First Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
>       `Last Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
>       Address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
>       City VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
>       State VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
>       Zip INT NOT NULL,
>       `Date of Birth` DATE NOT NULL,
>       `Major ID` INT,
>       Advisor VARCHAR(255),
>       `Enroll Date` DATE,
>       `Total Credits Complete` INT,
>       FOREIGN KEY `Major ID` REFERENCES Major(`Major ID`)
>  )
>  MySQL said:
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'REFERENCES Major(`Major ID`) )' at line 14

I would really appreciate it if someone could gear me in the right direction.

Thank you for taking your time to help me.

Comment: Foreign key name cannot contain spaces. Also, it is not a good practice to have spaces in column/table names etc. Use underscore instead of the spaces

Comment: There is no space in the fk name because the fk name is not specified in the above query.